# Scheduling timetables using Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

Currently, I'm reading a book named *Thinking as Computation* by [Hector J. Levesque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hector_Levesque). However, when I was trying to make attempts on exercises in **Chapter 5 - Case Study: Satisfying Constraints**, I encountered a problem with Question 7:

> Consider a course timetable for a Fine Arts student at a mythical university.
> The student wants to take a course in art, music, film, and dance, and each of
> these has three hours of classes a week. To accommodate a variety of timing
> constraints, some courses offer two sections at different times.
>
> There are two possible sections for art. One is offered MWF10, and the other,
> MWF11.
> There is a single section of dance: Friday 1–4.
> Music can be taken either Monday at 11, Wednesday at 3, and Friday at 3, or
> Monday at 2, Wednesday at 2, and Friday at 11.
> There are two sections of film: one on Monday at 11, Wednesday at 11,
> and Friday at noon, and one on Monday at noon, Wednesday at noon, and
> Wednesday at 3.
> In addition, the student wants a free hour for lunch each day at noon or 1.
> Write a Prolog program that generates a timetable for the student.

Until now, I have constructed an unfinished [Prolog program](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/timetable%20scheduling.pl). However, due to my inadequacy in the field of logic programming like Prolog (I'm only a novice on that language), I believe I cannot fulfil and demonstrate all the requirements shown in the question. The output I received is also unsatisfactory.

Any hints, steps or complete answers are appreciated.

Comment: Hiiii if possible can anyone of you answer my question? It will be greatly appreciated if you can eradicate my confusion now! :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't even dare to give an answer myself. Markus Triska made [an excellent video specifically on timetabling with Prolog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKvS62avplE).

Comment: Great suggestion! The video can be definitely referred to in my assignment :)